# Values in variables get flushed after function gets called in python

Tags: python, scheduler

I have created a function to fetch data from Database & use it inside the code. Inside that `DBRead()` function the values were able to printed, but unable to use in next sequence, it throws not defined error or empty values if defined at top.

I'm trying to fetch data from sqlite DB and use those data inside the code. The code fetches time and audio location (importantly) and play that audio at a scheduled time using scheduler. Trying to simplify the job function to only 1 (as there are lot of schedules needed up to 20). Currently stuck with this data flush error.
Eg:

```
print(audiofile)
print(jobid)
```

These gets printed inside the DBRead() and not after that inside the code. Throws #Empty or undefined error

Here is the full code below

```
import glob
import schedule
import time
import sqlite3
import pygame
from pygame import mixer #calling for pygame mixer to play audio files

pygame.mixer.init()
curr_daytype = 'Regular'
audiofile = ''
log_id = ''
daytype = ''
jobid = ''
#==========================================FUNCTIONS===========================================#
def DBRead():
   
    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect('pythontut.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `anno` ORDER BY `daytype` ASC") #Return All Data in Asc
    #cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM anno WHERE daytype = 'Regular'") #Return Daytype if Regular
    
    sql = "SELECT * FROM anno WHERE daytype ='"
    fetch_daytype = curr_daytype
    sql = sql + fetch_daytype + "'"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    fetch = cursor.fetchall()
    
    #print(fetch)
    for data in fetch:
        #tree.insert('', 'end', values=(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]))
        log_id = data[0]
        daytype = data[1]
        rec_time = data[2]
        audiofile = data[3]
        #print("Successfully read the data from database")
        print(log_id,daytype,rec_time,audiofile)
        
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    jobid = log_id
    print(audiofile)
    print(jobid)

"""
The fetch from cursor.fetchall returns this

[(41, '180MIN_Exam', '00:03:00 AM', 'audio\\8-start.mp3'), (40, '90MIN_Exam', '00:00:00 AM', ''),
(42, 'Saturday', '00:03:00 PM', 'audio\\8-start.mp3'), (43, 'Saturday', '00:03:00 PM', 'audio\\8-start.mp3')]

[(ID, 'Day Type', 'TIME', 'audio\\location.mp3'), (ID, 'Day Type', 'TIME', 'audio\\location.mp3')]

"""
def job1():
    print("file1.wav Playing...")
    mixer.music.load("1-start.mp3")
    #mixer.music.set_volume(0.9)
    mixer.music.play(1)
    
def job2():
    print("file2.wav Playing...")
    mixer.music.load("1-end.mp3")
    #mixer.music.set_volume(0.9)
    mixer.music.play(1)
    
def job3():
    print("2-start.mp3 Playing...")
    mixer.music.load("7-end.mp3")
    #mixer.music.set_volume(0.9)
    mixer.music.play(1)
    
def job4():
    print("2-end.mp3 Playing...")
    mixer.music.load("8-start.mp3")
    #mixer.music.set_volume(0.9)
    mixer.music.play(1)

#==========================================SIMPLIFIED FUNCTION====================================#
    
def job_to_play(jobid):
    #print("Day Type:" + daytype + "Time: " + rec_time + "," + jobid + " is Playing " + audiofile)
    print(jobid)
    
def curr_job():
    #DBRead()
    print('Current Job')
    print(log_id)
    curr_audiofile = "'" + audiofile + "'"
    print(curr_audiofile)
    mixer.music.load(curr_audiofile)
    #mixer.music.set_volume(0.9)
    mixer.music.play(1)
        
#============================================VARIABLES=============================================#

# relative path to search all text files (list)
audiolist = glob.glob("audio/*.mp3")
print(audiolist)

DBRead()
print(daytype) #Empty or undefined error
print(audiofile) #Empty or undefined error
print(jobid) #Empty or undefined error
if curr_daytype == "Regular":
    #schedule.every().day.at("14:31").do(jobid)
    #job_to_play(jobid)
    print(jobid)
    schedule.every().day.at("17:07").do(curr_job)

#==============================================TEST CODES================================================#
#Run job every day at specific HH:MM
schedule.every().day.at("12:45").do(job1)
schedule.every().day.at("13:07").do(job2)
schedule.every().day.at("14:31").do(job3)
schedule.every().day.at("14:31").do(job4)


#schedule.every().day.at("11:24").do(job1)
#schedule.every().day.at("11:25").do(job3)
#schedule.every().day.at("11:26").do(job2)
#schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job1)

"""
# Run job every day at specific HH:MM:SS
schedule.every().day.at("10:30:42").do(job)

# Run job on a specific day of the week
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)
    
# Run job every 3 second/minute/hour/day/week,
# Starting 3 second/minute/hour/day/week from now
schedule.every(3).seconds.do(job)
schedule.every(3).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every(3).hours.do(job)
schedule.every(3).days.do(job)
schedule.every(3).weeks.do(job)

# Run job every minute at the 23rd second
schedule.every().minute.at(":23").do(job)

# Run job every hour at the 42rd minute
schedule.every().hour.at(":42").do(job)

# Run jobs every 5th hour, 20 minutes and 30 seconds in.
# If current time is 02:00, first execution is at 06:20:30
schedule.every(5).hours.at("20:30").do(job)
"""

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You're not returning any values from your function. The variables created inside the function are local, and are destroyed once the function is finished running. Also, there's no reason to make `conn` and `cursor` global. Rewrite your function to accept arguments, use those arguments in your DB call, and return the values you need to use later.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).